# Spring data jpa not fetching all related row in Many to One mapping

Tags: spring-data-jpa, many-to-one

i have relationship ManyToOne between DiamondTracking and Diamond

List(37) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

DiamondTracking[0]:
diamond: Object

DiamondTracking[1]:
diamond: 1

DiamondTracking[2]:
diamond: 1

DiamondTracking[3]:
diamond: 1
and so on...

i am just able to retrive Diamond Object just for the first record. rest of the record give me only diamond id.
How can i retrive Diamond Object for all list records?

Comment: What is the code you are executing? What is this thing with curly braces supposed to be?

Comment: curly braces are the list of DiamondTracking  (List<DiamondTracking>). I am getting List<DiamondTracking> by using findByDiamond. and i am getting proper result too. but i just get Diamond object for the first list item. rest of the list item give just id for that Diamond.